# Display <script> result in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, lightning-community, header, third-party

my need is the following: i have two external resources that i can't put in static resources because they can be updated by a third party at any moment (they are not libraries)
I put these two resources in the header of my community because these tags aren't accepted in lwc.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='xxx-css' href='https://www.xxx.com/xxx/xxx/css/' type='text/css' media='all' />

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.xxxxx.com/xxx/xxx/js/' id='xxxx-js' />
```

and to display the rendering of all this, i need to create a lwc with only one tag

```
<div class="js-xxx" />
```

I tested and I have no rendering, I put the url of the script and the trusted site in the community and in salesforce to be sure.
so my question is : can I access the script from an lwc ?
and if it is not possible what solution do I have

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

No, the CSP (Content Security Policy) does not allow external scripts. This is a security feature. You can add [CSP Trusted Sites](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/csp_trusted_sites.htm), but you must still host the core application in a Static Resource; with `connect-src` enabled, it can reach the third-party server.